# Faye + nginx. Client closed keepalive connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket, passenger, faye

I am using faye on my production server with Passenger and Nginx. I write this code to nginx config file of my site:

```
location /faye {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

In a Chrome Network/Websocket I see

```
Status 101.
Switching protocols
```

As I know it means, that I have a websocket connection.
But I dont get any messages from it. In nginx.error.log I see:

```
2015/05/29 13:46:38 [info] 27188#0: *32 client closed keepalive connection
```

How can I fix it?